# Win 8.1 - Want to be available in Skype, not in Messenger

Tags: windows-8.1, skype

Just got a new machine with Windows 8.1.

Everytime I login into Skype, a Messenger account also shows up available to my contacts who use Win 8.1.

Edit: to make things clearer, I´m adding a print screen. 1 Skype open (Store app), two accounts visible. I don´t want the "Messenger" version there.

[image: Skype/Messenger logged in]

Is there a way to remove this Messenger auto log in function? Windows doesn´t allow me to use Skype without a MS account.

Thanks!

Filipe

Comment: Skype and Messenger are one in the same at this point.  Skype also only allows Microsoft Accounts Skype Accounts were retired over a year ago. Be sure your using the desktop client not the windows Store version of Skype.  If you had a Skype account you can currently still use it And login into Skype

Comment: @Rahmhound, tks for your answer. By using the Store version there is no way to avoid Messenger login, that´s it?

Comment: The `Windows Store` version does not log into Messenger, there is no Messenger Service anymore, it hasn't been running for months now.  Even the desktop version doesn't have that option anymore.

Comment: @Ramhound tks again. I Understand there is no Messenger Service anymore, though I didn´t make it clear. I updated my post with a print: same Skype client (Store app), two different logins (1 via Messenger). Is there a way to just log in with one of them via Store app?

Comment: Your contact is simply cached on your system.  Your messenger contact does not actual exist in this point in time.  They merged the two contact lists months ago.

Comment: It´s not my system, it´s another computer system. My contacts can choose if they talk to me through any of this accounts. Different conversation history, etc. Really annoying.

Comment: What?  Messenger does not exist.  So if they have your Messenger contact they should simply remove it.